# Custom postgres FTS dictionary

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

We've built some software that searches accounting data (orders, customers, etc) which often has a user-visible number padded with leading zeroes. Users would like to use full text search, but not have to type all those leading zeros. eg: searching for "12345" matches "0000012345"

It seems to me that the most elegant solution would be a custom dictionary that operated on `uint` tokens. Unfortunately, I am having real difficulty finding any documentation on writing lexer functions. Ideally, I would like to write such a function in SQL or pl/SQL rather than having to resort to maintaining a C extension.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create your own dictionary template. For this you need to create files: zero_dict.c, zero_dict.sql.in, Makefile. And copy them to the directory "contrib/zero_dict".

File zero_dict.c:

```
#include "postgres.h"
#include "fmgr.h"
#include "tsearch/ts_public.h"

#ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
#endif

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(dzero_init);
Datum dzero_init(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);

Datum
dzero_init(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    PG_RETURN_POINTER(NULL);
}

PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(dzero_lexize);
Datum dzero_lexize(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS);

Datum
dzero_lexize(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS)
{
    char       *in = (char *) PG_GETARG_POINTER(1);
    int32       len = PG_GETARG_INT32(2);
    char       *txt;
    TSLexeme   *res;
    int         n;

    if ((n = strspn(in, "0")) != 0 && in[n] != '\0')
    {
        txt = pnstrdup(in + n, len - n);
        res = palloc0(sizeof(TSLexeme) * 2);
        res[0].lexeme = txt;
        PG_RETURN_POINTER(res);
    }
    else
    {
        PG_RETURN_POINTER(NULL);
    }
}
```

File zero_dict.sql.in:

```
SET search_path = public;
BEGIN;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dzero_init(internal)
     returns internal
     as 'MODULE_PATHNAME'
     language C;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dzero_lexize(internal,internal,internal,internal)
    returns internal
    as 'MODULE_PATHNAME'
    language C
    with (isstrict);

CREATE TEXT SEARCH TEMPLATE zerodict(
    LEXIZE = dzero_lexize,
    INIT = dzero_init);

END;
```

File Makefile:

```
subdir = contrib/zero_dict
top_builddir = ../..
include $(top_builddir)/src/Makefile.global

MODULE_big = zero_dict
OBJS =  zero_dict.o
DATA_built = zero_dict.sql
DOCS =

include $(top_srcdir)/contrib/contrib-global.mk
```

Then you need to execute the following commands:

```
make
make install
psql DBName < zero_dict.sql
```

If you will create the dictionary:

```
create text search dictionary zerodict (template=zerodict);
```

And you can execute the query:

```
dicts=# select ts_lexize('zerodict', '0000012345');
 ts_lexize 
-----------
 {12345}
(1 row)
```

For more information you can look over:
http://www.sai.msu.su/~megera/postgres/fts/fts.pdf